# Can we develop a student management portal with dotnetnuke?

Tags: dotnetnuke

I need to develop a student management portal, where students upload projects (documentation, videos, screenshots and source code) and Admin approves them and give them points. Is this possible with dotnetnuke? If this is possible then which module should I use?.

Please Reply.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I need to build this portal real fast. Please suggest me technologies to do the same if building that with dotnetnuke is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

DotNetNuke is a bad choice for this.  From your brief description of the problem, a simple Content Management System (CMS) will not be able to do this.  What you describe is approaching "courseware", or a Learning Management System (LMS).  Either that, or you need a custom-built site.  Either way, I don't think "real fast" is possible.  Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of modules available. I don't have any experience with them. http://store.dotnetnuke.com/home/product-list/searchtext/lms